# Register WooCommerce refunds as order meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are trying to add the refund amount, to a custom order meta field, but we are having some issues.

I am having some trouble finding the right information and currently I only have an action and what I think is the order refund amount:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ){
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_custom_meta_key', 'my data' );
} , 10, 2);
```

And this is what I think is the right way of getting the refund, but it should be attached to a custom meta.

```
WC_Order()->get_refunds();
```

If any one can help, I would really appreciate it.

**Edit:**

I have found the following hook, for when an order is being refunded. I guess I should use that, so the amount will be registered as custom meta when the order is refunded?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_refunded', 'action_woocommerce_order_refunded', 10, 2 ); 
function action_woocommerce_order_refunded( $order_id, $refund_id ) 
{ 
  // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it works for me.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_refunded', 'action_woocommerce_order_refunded', 10, 2 ); 
function action_woocommerce_order_refunded( $order_id, $refund_id ) 
{ 
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'refund_amount', $order->get_total_refunded() );
    $order->save();
}
```